# Flink all zero monitoring

Tags: docker, apache-flink, monitoring, zero

Flink has all-zero listening in the Docker container. Binding 0.0.0.0 is equivalent to binding all IP addresses of the local host, causing network-wide listening. If the management plane, control plane, and user plane are divided on the local host, the original isolation principle of the system will be violated. For example, run the netstat -nultp command in jobmanager.

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6123            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1100/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6124            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1100/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1100/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50100           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1100/java

All-zero monitoring can cause some security problems. Can anyone give us an opinion on how to solve the all-zero monitoring problem?

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  Within the context of a Docker container, 0.0.0.0 means to listen on all interfaces _of the container_, not the containing host; usually you're required to set processes to listen to 0.0.0.0 so they can accept connections from the host or other containers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.